# Jquery How to Do Show and Hide Multiple Elements on Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Say I have 3 color box, White, Black, Blue. And there are 3 color editors, White, Black, Blue.

If user click White box, the White editor show, then the Black and Blue editor is hide.

If user click Black box, the Black editor show, then the White and Blue editor is hide.

I do it this way using jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){        

    jQuery("#white").click(function() {
        jQuery(".editor_white").prop("disabled", false);
        jQuery(".editor_white").show();
        jQuery(".editor_black, .editor_blue").prop("disabled", true);
        jQuery(".editor_black, .editor_blue").hide();
    });

    jQuery("#black").click(function() {
        jQuery(".editor_black").prop("disabled", false);
        jQuery(".editor_black").show();
        jQuery(".editor_white, .editor_blue").prop("disabled", true);
        jQuery(".editor_white, .editor_blue").hide();
    });

});
```

I have so many color box and color editors, so I have to write very long code using the above method.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: can you share your html too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142385/is-it-possible-to-write-this-jquery-code-shorter-beginner or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971427/how-do-i-write-this-shorter-with-jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925434/javascript-jquery-shorthand-code-and-active-function or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636249/how-can-i-optimize-this-jquery-code

Comment: At max you do following At max you can do following 

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){        
    
        jQuery("#white").click(function() {
            jQuery(".editor_white").prop("disabled", false).show();
            jQuery(".editor_black, .editor_blue").prop("disabled", true).hide();
        });
    
        jQuery("#black").click(function() {
            jQuery(".editor_black").prop("disabled", false).show();
            jQuery(".editor_white, .editor_blue").prop("disabled", true).hide();
        });
    
    });


Do cascading of events.

Comment: Use a common class and write your selectors like `$('.editor').not(this)` -- http://api.jquery.com/not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all your editor boxes a second class, hide them all then show the appropriate one

Example: assuming your second class is '.editor-box'

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){        

    jQuery("#white").click(function() {

        //Make sure this happens first
        jQuery(".editor-box").prop("disabled", true);
        jQuery(".editor-box").hide();

        //Show the appropriate box
        jQuery(".editor_white").prop("disabled", false);
        jQuery(".editor_white").show();

    });

    . . . // Rinse and repeat for the remaining selectors
});
```

If you want to go a step further, give your selector boxes a class too..then save the colour
on that element using the data api:
Example: Assuming your boxes have a class called '.colour-box'

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){        

    jQuery(".colour-box").click(function() {

        var colour = $(this).data('colour')

        //Make sure this happens first
        jQuery(".editor-box").prop("disabled", true);
        jQuery(".editor-box").hide();

        //Show the appropriate box
        jQuery(".editor_" + colour).prop("disabled", false);
        jQuery(".editor_" + colour).show();

    });

    . . . // The End - No need to repeat for the remaining selectors
});
```

This second method will work for any number of colours, using this single event handler on the '.colour-box' class.

Assuming you have a button with the tag '#white' for example

This:

```
<button id="#white" type="button">White</button>
```

...becomes this:

```
<button class="colour-box" data-colour="white" type="button">White</button>
```

Comment: But code lines are similar to OP .

Comment: What if he has four colours? e.g yellow? His current code would be

    `jQuery(".editor_white, .editor_blue, .editor_yellow").hide();`

This method shortens that line by selecting them all using a second class

Comment: Thanks Abimbola, the second method really simplify the code :)